# Steam API Failed to forward request message to internal server

Tags: steam-web-api

I'm trying to check if user purchased an application with request like this:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/CheckAppOwnership/v1?key=< VALID_KEY>&appid=< VALID_APP_ID>&steamid=<...>'
```

Every parameter is valid and was successfully used in other requests, but with all requests to ISteamUser I get same strange error

```
Failed to forward request message to internal server
```

And same error when requesting partner.steam-api.com

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems like a bug in steam api

Comment: did you solved your issue?